# MVC - Remote validation for the blur event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to verify that a code entered into the web page is valid by reading a backend database when the text box loses focus. I am able to execute the code in the controller but for some reason the model object is not being passed to the controller method.

The text box definition...

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HSDRepCode)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HSDRepCode, new { placeholder = "Enter your HSD Rep code...", @class = "contact-name"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HSDRepCode)
</div>
```

The javascript code for the blur event...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#HSDRepCode").blur(function () {
        var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';

        $.ajax({
            url: "/CRM/ValidateHSDRep",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("model").serialize(),
            dataType: "application/json"
            }).done(function( model ) {
                $("#HSFirstName").val(model.HSFirstName);
                $("#HSLastName").val(model.HSLastName);
                });
        });
    </script>
```

The CRM controller code...

```
public ActionResult ValidateHSDRep(LeadInfo leadInfo)
    {
        HSDRep hsdRep = new HSDRep();

        hsdRep = CRMModels.ValidateHSDRepCode(leadInfo.HSDRepCode);

        return Json(leadInfo);
    }
```

The controller code is executed but the leadInfo object is all nulls after entering the HSDRepCode and tabbing to the next text box.

Why isn't the model being passed to the controller code?

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Why would you send back the whole model when all you need is one property? But if you do want to degrade performance, then its `data: $('form').serialize(),` to post back the values in the controls.

Comment: I'm sending back the whole model because I want to return two additional values. If there is a better way I would like to know what it is. Thanks

Comment: Just send back only what you need - `data: $(this).val(),` and return only what you need - `return Json(new {firstName = leadInfo.HSFirstName ,lastName: leadInfo.HSFirstName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`- far better performance. (and its a GET, not a POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model variable doesn´t have the serialize() method, this method is just to use with forms elements.
Try remove the single quote from this line: var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); 
Now send the model object as the data: model.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#HSDRepCode").blur(function () {
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    if(model == null) {
        model = {};
    }

    model.HSDRepCode = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/CRM/ValidateHSDRep",
        type: "POST",
        data: model,
        dataType: "application/json"
    }).done(function (model) {
        $("#HSFirstName").val(model.HSFirstName);
        $("#HSLastName").val(model.HSLastName);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the 'var model' line and set the data line to 'data: model' and I received an error that said "model" was undefined.

Comment: I´m sorry, I was not clear, don´t remove the line but just the single quote, I edit my answer.

Comment: The I added var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); back in, without the single quotes and changed the data line to data: model, but I don't have any data in the model. Every attribute is null.

Comment: Is you Model with null properties too? Because if you do @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), the properties will be in the initial state, the state that you send to your View, it won´t be updated dynamically as you type in the input. If you want to send the value that is in the field, make model.HSDRepCode = $(this).val() before. The other properties will be null too, so you need to fill them before the AJAX.

Comment: I receive the error Unable to set property 'HSDRepCode' of undefined or null reference. This is what is in my javascript routine var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); model.HSDRepCode = $(this).val()  This what it is when I receive the error var model = null;          model.HSDRepCode = $(this).val(). As you can see the var model ends up being null, which why I receive the error.

Comment: Yes, check the code above, if the model is null I initialise it model = {};